# Why doesn't C++ need forward declarations for class members?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I was under the impression that everything in C++ must be declared before being used.

In fact, I remember reading that *this is the reason* why the use of `auto` in return types is not valid C++0x without something like `decltype`: the compiler must know the declared type **before** evaluating the function body.

Imagine my surprise when I noticed (after a long time) that the following code is in fact perfectly legal:

*[Edit: Changed example.]*

```
class Foo
{
    Foo(int x = y);
    static const int y = 5;
};
```

So now I don't understand:

#### Why doesn't the compiler require a forward declaration inside classes, when it requires them in other places?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard says (section 3.3.7):

> The potential scope of a name declared in a class consists not only of the declarative region following the name’s point of declaration, but also of all function bodies, brace-or-equal-initializers of non-static data members, and default arguments in that class (including such things in nested classes).

This is probably accomplished by delaying processing bodies of inline member functions until after parsing the entire class definition.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what is a "potential scope", and how it is related here.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The (potential) scope of an identifier, is the portion of the source code where that name is usable.  According to the introductory text for 3.3, *potential scope* differs from *scope* because a local variable by the same name can hide the class member.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I guess that answers the question of "why doesn't my code produce an error?" but not the underlying question of "why did they make the language this way?", i.e. why is the requirement for forward declarations different inside vs. outside of classes?

Comment: @Mehrdad: It's rather vital to the ability to write member function bodies inside the class definition.  I suppose that isn't strictly necessary either, but it sure is convenient.

Comment: I'm confused... why wouldn't just having a forward declaration work in the case of a member function, just like a global function?

Comment: @Mehrdad: You can't actually have forward declarations of class members.

Comment: Right, but why? Is there a better reason for this than "that's just how it works"?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I think only Bjarne could tell you that.

Answer (score 6):

Function definitions within the class body are treated as if they were actually defined after the class has been defined. So your code is equivalent to:

```
class Foo
{
    Foo();
    int x, *p;
};
inline Foo::Foo() { p = &x; }
```

Comment: there should be a ; after the first Foo() declaration inside the class if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @K-ballo: That makes sense for my example, but not in general. Why does this compile, then, if `y` is undeclared? `class Foo
{
 Foo(int x = y);
 static const int y = 5;
};`

Comment: That's a good one, I guess there is a special rule for default parameters in inline member functions? I would like to hear the answer for that too!

Comment: No, it's not equivalent.  `Foo::Foo` is no longer `inline` after your modifications, and would generate multiple definition errors.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I think you need to reverse the question to understand it.

*Why does C++ require forward declaration ?*

Because of the way C++ works (include files, not modules), it would otherwise need to wait for the whole Translation Unit before being able to assess, for sure, what the functions are. There are several downsides here:

- compilation time would take yet another hit
- it would be nigh impossible to provide any guarantee for code in headers, since any introduction of a later function could invalidate it all

*Why is a class different ?*

A class is by definition contained. It's a small unit (or should be...). Therefore:

- there is little compilation time issue, you can wait until the class end to start analyzing
- there is no risk of dependency hell, since all dependencies are clearly identified and isolated

Therefore we can eschew this annoying forward-declaration rule for classes.

Comment: That's a great point, but then why does it need forward declarations for things like return type inference?

Comment: @Mehrdad: in C++ function signatures precede the bodies. Other languages infer the argument/return types from the body (see Hindley-Milner for an example of algorithm used), but C++ does not. It certainly simplifies compiler implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing: the compiler saves the body of the function and doesn't actually process it until the class declaration is complete.

Comment: Nice answer, but see my modified example.

Comment: @Mehrdad, the default parameter will not be evaluated until the function is actually called.

Comment: @Mark: Although default arguments aren't evaluated until the call, that doesn't mean that name resolution is performed at the call site.  For example, function overloads (at namespace scope) introduced between the class body and the call site will not be considered.

Answer (score 0):

unlike a namespace, a class' scope cannot be reopened. it is bound.

imagine implementing a class in a header if everything needed to be declared in advance. i presume that since it is bound, it was more logical to write the language as it is, rather than requiring the user to write forwards in the class (or requiring definitions separate from declarations).